# Find if a String in a list of Strings is in another list of Strings in Esper

Tags: java, mule, esper, epl

I'm working with Esper + Mule and I am trying to define a POJO and an Event, but after reading the documentation of Espero I haven't found what I really need.

My event, represented by a POJO, has a property like this:

```
List<String> Words;
```

What I would like to do is use the keyword IN to compare it with another list of words, so the pattern would look like this:

```
... Words in ('word1', 'word2', 'word3) ...
```

But I get this error:

```
Collection or array comparison is not allowed for the IN, ANY, SOME or ALL keywords
```

Is there any way to achieve this?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to create a method to do what you want, register that method with esper, and reference that method from your EPL statement:

Create helper class (for this example, I use EsperUtils.java):

```
package my.package;

class EsperUtils {
  public static boolean contains(List<String> list1, List<String> list2) {

    // Check for list1 and list2 to contain same word
    for (String s1 : list1) {
      for (String s2 : list2) {
        if (s1.equals(s2)) return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }
}
```

Register method with esper in aem.esper.config.xml:

```
<plugin-singlerow-function name="contains" function-class="my.package.EsperUtils" function-method="contains" />
```

Use the helper method in your EPL:

```
select * from myEvent where contains(Words,AnotherListOfWords)
```

You could also add the helper method to your event POJO instead of a helper class.

Answer (score 0):

You'd want to look at enumeration methods, see http://esper.codehaus.org/esper-4.9.0/doc/reference/en-US/html_single/index.html#enumerationreference
It seems that "intersect" and "countOf" in combination would suit.

Comment: I can not make it work this way since Esper needs all the parameters to be events. Or at least that's what I understand from the errors.