# looking for a value in indexed or collection property using Esper

Tags: esper

I have an event which has indexed property ids (List ). How to write query which matches a value in ids ?

```
class MyEvent
{
    private List<Integer> allIds;
    getters/setters
}
```

Comment: Have a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18440941/find-if-a-string-in-a-list-of-strings-is-in-another-list-of-strings-in-esper

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the enumeration method such as "allIds.where(v => v = 5)"